# Convert Switch to Non-virtual Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I currently have a C++ interface

```
void foo() ...
```

and lots of implementions

```
void A::foo();
void B::foo();
```

Currently foo is defined as follows

```
struct Wrapper
{
    void foo()
    {
        if(state == STATE_A) a.foo();
        else if(state == STATE_B) b.foo();
    }
    union {
        A a;
        B b;
    };
    State state;
}
//....
Wrapper a(STATE_A, existingA);
Wrapper b(STATE_B, existingB);
a.foo(); b.foo();
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I have multiple foo() like functions and multiple A/B like classes. It's getting tedious/error prone to write all the cases.

Note that I cannot use virtual functions (this runs inside a N^5 loop... with 10 million+ executions / second). I want the compiler to inline this, hard.

I have thought of collecting A's, B's, etc together and computing them in a data oriented fashion, but unfortunately I can't do that (due to algorithm concerns)

Comment: `It's getting tedious/error prone to write all the cases.` That's what happens when you discard language features and choose to code it yourself directly. That's why those language features exist in the first place: because someone got tired of writing the boilerplate.

Comment: To add, how is this better than using virtual dispatch? Even if this were optimized with an index (such as array lookup) rather than an if-else chain, this would be equivalent to using virtual dispatch (in terms of implementation for most compilers). That is, STATE_X represents a vtable, and Wrapper::foo is like vtable lookup...

Comment: Have you actually measured straightforward implementation with virtual functions? 3-5 "if" conditions could easily match cost of virtual function call. And there is no guarantee that inline actually happens if function growth large enough...

Comment: @trinithis can it be inlined?

Comment: @jameszhao00: How do you know that your switch method can be inlined?

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry should've given some examples of foo(). A lot of cases are just "return this->k", "return this->m * cos(this->l)", etc.

Comment: I fail to see how exactly is your question related to `parallel-processing`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Removed it for you :) I originally tagged it as such because this system is a graphics (global illumination using path tracing) application. But you're right the question isn't really related to parallel processing.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the compiler to inline this, hard.

That's not going to happen.

You're using *runtime polymorphism*. By definition, the compiler *cannot know* which function will be called at call time. You are going to pay for virtual dispatch, whether you do it manually or let the compiler do it.

The absolute *most* inlining you will get is in the calls to the member functions. It still has to do a conditional branch based on a memory access (fetching the "type") to get to the "inline" part. And every new "state" you add will add *another* condition to that branch. At best, this will become a state table... which is no different from just a virtual function pointer: it fetches from a memory address, and uses that to branch to a particular piece of code.

Just like a vtable pointer, only you wasted your time implementing something the compiler could do for you.

I strongly advise you to *profile* this instead of simply assuming that your hand-written method can beat the compiler.

---

If you've decided to abandon language-level polymorphism, then you should use a [`boost.variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) and appropriate visitors instead. Your code would look like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<A, B> Wrapper;

struct FooVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  template <typename T> void operator()(T &t) {t.foo()};
};
```

You will have to make a `FooVisitor` for every function you want to call. To call it, you do this:

```
Wrapper a = existingA;
boost::apply_visitor(FooVisitor(), a);
```

Obviously, you can wrap that in a simple function:

```
void CallFoo(Wrapper &a) {boost::apply_visitor(FooVisitor(), a);}
```

Indeed, you can make a whole template family of these:

```
template<typename Visitor>
void Call(Wrapper &a) {boost::apply_visitor(Visitor(), a);}
```

Note that parameter passing is not allowed (you have to store the parameters in the visitor itself), but they can have return values (you have to put the return type in the `boost::static_visitor<Typename_Here>` declaration of your visitor).

Also note that `boost::variant` objects have value semantics, so copies will copy the internal object. You can also use the `boost::get()` syntax to get the actual type, but I would not suggest it unless you *really* need it. Just use visitors.

Comment: Also, I'm currently holding Wrapper in contiguously allocated memory. I could use placement new and have something with max(sizeof(A), sizeof(B)) size holding the polymorphic object... but then it also gets a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. You can do the function selection at compile time, or you can do it at run time. If it's run time you're not going to do better than the existing virtual mechanism. If it's compile time you need different code for each type you're going to use, but you can use templates to automate the process.

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    void foo()
    {
        t.foo();
    }
    T t;
};
```

Of course this example is highly abstracted and I can't see any difference between using the `Wrapper` class and the template type directly. You'll have to flesh out your example a little more to get a better answer.